# Remove fields from dialog window

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

How can I remove fields from the CKEditor dialog window?
In my case, I need to remove the "Caption" field from the "Table Properties" window. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple: remove the caption tag from the allowed HTML tags in "/admin/config/content/formats" :-)